# If $f$ is differentiable but unbounded on some interval $(a,b)$ then $f'$ is unbounded on $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here as the integrability of $f'$ is not given I don't think that we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus.
So I tried to the fact that $\forall M>0, \exists c\in(a,b)$ such that $|f'(c)|>M$.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Suppose $f’$ is bounded: what can you say about $f$?

Comment: Hi, So if it is bounded then $\exists M$ such that $\forall x\in(a,b)$, $|f'(x)|\leq M$. And then how do I relate it with $f$? Mean value theorem?

Comment: For instance, or fundamental theorem of calculus... what property do you get about $f$?

Comment: Still I'm a bit confused. Could you please elaborate more

Comment: @Mindlack Instead of fundamental theorem of calculus, I think the mean value theorem is more natural to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f’$ is bounded by some $M >0$. Let $c$ be the average of $a$ and $b$. Let $x \in (a,b)$, then $f(x)=f(c)+f’(t)(x-c)$ for some $t \in (a,b)$ by the mean value theorem. Therefore $|f(x)| \leq |f(c)| + \frac{M(b-a)}{2}$.